# Beta build crash report debugging through Xcode Organizer -> Crashes

Tags: xcode, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I have submitted my app for beta testing and review, few users have reported random crashes and i am trying to fix crashes for that
I have successfully downloaded the crash reports using Xcode Organizer, According to the apple's document **The stack frame where the crash occurred is highlighted in orange** but in crash reports there is no highlighted orange  in my case, and on clicking the stack frame(by clicking the arrow) it open the project but shows the last state of Xcode Project doesn't shows the file and line where the crash actually happened.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
following are the steps to trace out the crash reports.
1. Open organizer and select crashes.
2. Select the build submitted to Appstore from the left panel of organizer  window under ios apps.
3. Select any crash log under the Appstore->app version
4. Right click on crash log and select show in finder.
5. Again right click on the xxx.xccrashpoints(log file) and select show package contents.
6. Go to the path Distributionlogs->all->logs to see all the crash reports.
7. Move all the .crash file to any folder on desktop.
8. Connect your iOS device with mac machine, open xcode(if not open) and go to Window->Devices->select you ios Device -> view device logs.
9. Drag all the .crash reports(refer step 6,7) under all logs tab, and there you go.. you can see that your crash logs are desymbolicated, you can see the method name causing the crash.
```

App store release builds are already desymbolicated for you and you can   click on the small arrow icon to reach to the line no. causing the crash.  This is mainly for beta release.

Comment: This seems to work but is pretty annoying. Is there any other option to desymbolicate the crashes from beta tests within the Xcode Organizer > Crashes panel?

Comment: @benrudhart for beta tests this is the only known way to me, for production/live build you will find a small arrow button right next to the stack trace of crash which will take you to the line number causing the crash.